# Cartan subalgebras of a semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a semisimple complex Lie algebra and $H$ a Cartan subalgebra. Suppose that $L=L_{1}\oplus ...\oplus L_{k}$ with each $L_{i}$ a simple ideal of $L$. Show that for $1\leq i \leq k$, $H\cap L_{i}$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $L_{i}$.

I have had no thoughts on this problem and no idea how to solve it hence I cannot make an attempt. I have seriously severe difficulties.

Comment: It is a bad idea to write «its Cartan subalgebra», for the Cartan subalgebra is not unique.

Comment: Same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172722/cartan-subalgebra-proof).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I have reworded this.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The link you gave leads to "Page not found"

Comment: Yes, the question was deleted and then asked again. But the link is still there.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi_i\colon L\rightarrow L\cap L_i$ be the canonical projection to the $i$-th factor. We can use now the following lemma:

*Lemma:* Let $\phi:L\rightarrow L'$ be a surjective Lie algebra homomorphism, and $H$ be a Cartan subalgebra of $L$. Then $\phi(H)$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $L'$.

Proof: See Lemma $3.6.2$ [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=95lyvIfX164C&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=cartan+subalgebra+L1%2BL2&source=bl&ots=H3OPWfun7B&sig=02pwyckafsYySqtmp-n9xWH7PZI&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj21YmrkcDSAhUhM5oKHZZ4Bz4Q6AEINDAD#v=onepage&q=cartan%20subalgebra%20L1%2BL2&f=false). The proof works also for not necessarily semisimple Lie algebras.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $C_i$ be the Cartan subalgebra of $L_i$, $\oplus_iC_i$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $L$ since it is Abelian and equal to its normalizer. $(\oplus_iC_i)\cap L_i=C_i$.

If $D$ is another Cartan subalgebra, there exists an automorphism $f$ of $L$ such that $f(\oplus_iC_i)=D$ (see property 3) in the reference. Such an automorphism sends a simple component to a simple component, We can write $f(C_i)=D_{f(i)}$ where $f(C_i)\subset L_{f(i)}$. We can write $D=\oplus_iD_i$.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CartanSubalgebra.html

Comment: You showed that there exist Cartan subalgebras whose intersections with the summands are Cartan subalgebras there, but the question is whether *every* Cartan subalgebra had that property.